# SCR Reference Annotation Not Updating to OSGI Reference Annotation (says, "annotation type not applicable to this kind of declaration")

Tags: osgi, aem, declarative-services

I have this component,

```java
package com.path.http.impl;

import com.path.api.http.ClientManager;
import com.path.http.ConnectionManager;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Component;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Reference;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.ReferenceCardinality;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.ReferencePolicy;
import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Service;
import org.apache.sling.commons.osgi.PropertiesUtil;

import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap;

@Component
@Service
public final class DefaultClientManager implements ClientManager {
    @Reference(cardinality        = ReferenceCardinality.OPTIONAL_MULTIPLE,
               policy             = ReferencePolicy.DYNAMIC,
               bind               = "bindConnectionManager",
               unbind             = "unbindConnectionManager",
               referenceInterface = ConnectionManager.class)
    private final ConcurrentMap<String, Client> clients = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    @Override
    public Optional<Client> getClient(final String id) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(this.clients.get(id));
    }

    protected void bindConnectionManager(final ConnectionManager   connectionManager,
                                         final Map<String, Object> properties) {
        final Client client = connectionManager.getClient();
        this.clients.put(
            PropertiesUtil.toString(properties.get(DefaultConnectionManagerImpl.MANAGER_ID), ""),
            client
        );
    }

    protected void unbindConnectionManager(final ConnectionManager   connectionManager,
                                           final Map<String, Object> properties) {
        this.clients.remove(
            PropertiesUtil.toString(properties.get(DefaultConnectionManagerImpl.MANAGER_ID), "")
        );
    }
}
```

And I wanted to update it from the SCR annotations to the newer OSGI ones.

I wound up with something like:

```java
package com.path.http.impl;

import com.path.http.ClientManager;
import com.path.http.ConnectionManager;
import com.path.http.impl.DefaultConnectionManagerImpl;
import org.apache.sling.commons.osgi.PropertiesUtil;
import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Component;
import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Reference;
import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.ReferenceCardinality;
import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.ReferencePolicy;

import jakarta.ws.rs.client.Client;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentMap;

@Component(service = ClientManager.class)
public final class DefaultClientManager implements ClientManager {
    @Reference(cardinality = ReferenceCardinality.MULTIPLE,
               policy      = ReferencePolicy.DYNAMIC,
               bind        = "bindConnectionManager",
               unbind      = "unbindConnectionManager",
               service     = ConnectionManager.class)
    private final ConcurrentMap<String, Client> clients = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Client>();

    @Override
    public Optional<Client> getClient(final String id) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(this.clients.get(id));
    }

    protected void bindConnectionManager(final ConnectionManager   connectionManager,
                                         final Map<String, Object> properties) {
        this.clients
            .put(PropertiesUtil.toString(properties.get(DefaultConnectionManagerImpl.MANAGER_ID),
                                         ""),
                 connectionManager.getClient());
    }

    protected void unbindConnectionManager(final ConnectionManager   connectionManager,
                                           final Map<String, Object> properties) {
        this.clients
            .remove(PropertiesUtil.toString(properties.get(DefaultConnectionManagerImpl.MANAGER_ID),
                                            ""));
    }
}
```

Now, I still don't understand everything so there are some parts which make me uncertain (for example, can I expect my `bind` and `unbind` methods to still get passed a `Map` of properties, with OSGI?).

But the primary issue I'm running into is these two errors from my Maven build:

```
[ERROR] …/src/main/java/com/path/http/impl/DefaultClientManager.java:[22,30] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method bind()
  location: @interface org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Reference
[ERROR] …/src/main/java/com/path/http/impl/DefaultClientManager.java:[20,5] annotation type not applicable to this kind of declaration
```

Removing `bind` from the `@Reference` annotation gets rid of the first error (though not what I want to do, in the end) but the second one always remains, even if I get rid of all optional elements.

Reading the JavaDocs, it does say, "Annotated field - There is no bind method name," but that's also in the context of what it defaults to if the optional element isn't provided so it's not clear to me whether `bind` can be or cannot be used with a field, like this (`unbind` has the same documentation wording but does not throw an error when I leave it).

As far as I can tell, I'm creating a 1-to-1 conversion of the original class, using the new annotations' and libraries' equivalents so I don't understand why this won't work.

Even if the `@Reference` wouldn't work on deployment, I'm pretty certain that OSGI `@Reference`s *can* be used for fields, still, so I don't understand why Maven is still complaining when I remove all optional elements from the annotation.

At a high level, I'd love to understand how to convert my old component into one which uses OSGI annotations. At a more specific level, I would happily settle to understand why my `@Reference` annotation doesn't seem to want to work with the field, if I'm using any of the optional elements incorrectly.

My Maven dependencies, for the newer code, are:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
  <artifactId>org.osgi.service.component.annotations</artifactId>
  <version>1.5.1</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
  <artifactId>org.osgi.service.metatype.annotations</artifactId>
  <version>1.4.1</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>jakarta.ws.rs</groupId>
  <artifactId>jakarta.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
  <artifactId>org.apache.sling.commons.osgi</artifactId>
  <version>2.4.2</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents.client5</groupId>
  <artifactId>httpclient5</artifactId>
  <version>5.2.1</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.connectors</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-apache-connector</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Java version is `8`; AEM version is `6.5.15` (though I am running into the Maven error before anything actually gets deployed to the running AEM instance).

And `ClientManager` is just a simple `interface` which looks like:

```java
package com.path.http;

import jakarta.ws.rs.client.Client;
import java.util.Optional;

public interface ClientManager {
    Optional<Client> getClient(final String id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove final from field. If you want to set via setter then annotate setter with @Reference.

Comment: No luck, I'm afraid. Removing `final` still results in the same errors.

Comment: Did you also try to only set the @Reference annotation on the bind method. Also bind methods should be public.

Answer (score 0):

The `@Reference` annotation is in a wrong place. It should annotate the "bind" method, not the Map. Change the code as follows and you will be good:

```
@Component(service = ClientManager.class)
public final class DefaultClientManager implements ClientManager {
    private final ConcurrentMap<String, Client> clients = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    @Reference(cardinality = ReferenceCardinality.MULTIPLE,
            policy      = ReferencePolicy.DYNAMIC,
            bind        = "bindConnectionManager",
            unbind      = "unbindConnectionManager",
            service     = ConnectionManager.class)
    protected void bindConnectionManager(final ConnectionManager   connectionManager,
                                         final Map<String, Object> properties) {
        this.clients
                .put(PropertiesUtil.toString(properties.get(DefaultConnectionManagerImpl.MANAGER_ID),
                                ""),
                        connectionManager.getClient());
    }

    protected void unbindConnectionManager(final ConnectionManager   connectionManager,
                                           final Map<String, Object> properties) {
        this.clients
                .remove(PropertiesUtil.toString(properties.get(DefaultConnectionManagerImpl.MANAGER_ID),
                        ""));
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<Client> getClient(final String id) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(this.clients.get(id));
    }

}
```

Comment: I'll try that out; is there a reason this annotation cannot be applied to a field, anymore? The documentation (assuming I'm looking in the right place) still says, "When the annotation is applied to a field, …" (https://docs.osgi.org/javadoc/osgi.cmpn/8.1.0/org/osgi/service/component/annotations/Reference.html).

Comment: The documentation sais "When the annotation is applied to a method, the method is the bind method of the reference." and this is what's happening

Comment: Correct but it also clearly says that it can, also, be applied to a field; the code I'm working with, originally, was written with the annotation on the field and I could easily find examples online of the same so this use case used to be perfectly acceptable; considering the documentation hasn't changed for several versions, I don't think they meant that "if the field has a corresponding method" but the direct application to either a field or method or etc.